# Initializing inlined arrays in structs - how to make sure I don't mess it up?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

It may be that at times, for performance reasons, I may decide to define a struct such as

```
typedef struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    int offset;
    void* data[];
} ring_buffer;
```

inlining `data` in the struct itself. I'm currently then defining the creation function as

```
ring_buffer* ring_buffer_create(size_t capacity) {
    int struct_size = 
      sizeof(int) + 2 * sizeof(size_t) + 
      capacity * sizeof(void*);
    ring_buffer* rb = (ring_buffer*)malloc(struct_size);
    rb->capacity = capacity;
    rb->offset = 0;
    rb->size = 0;
    return rb;
}
```

which (if I didn't miscalculate anything) will work fine as long as the C compiler doesn't do some weird field padding / alignments.

How do people in general deal with this situation (other than defining `data` to be a pointer, of course)?

Thanks

Comment: Please read [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member) Do e.g. `ring_buffer = malloc(sizeof(ring_buffer) + capacity * sizeof(void *))`

Comment: Ah, the idea with your code snippet is to overallocate by "a bit" to guarantee that when I access `rb->data` for a given size I'm always in a valid memory region?

Comment: That's how [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) work. It's part of the C language. The only other way is to use a pointer and have a separate allocation for it.

Comment: Cool, thx. Maybe move your comments to a full-fledged reply?

Comment: The correct computation is `sizeof(ring_buffer) + capacity * sizeof(void*)`. Or `sizeof *rb + capacity * sizeof rb->data[0]`. (I'd use the second one on general principles.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your size calculation is incorrect: the structure could have embedded padding to ensure the alignment of some of its members. For example on 64-bit targets, `int` is 4 bytes and the `void *data[]` array that follows requires 8-byte alignment, so the compiler will insert 4 bytes of padding before the `data` member.

The size should be computed this way:

```
size_t struct_size = sizeof(ring_buffer) + capacity * sizeof(void *);
```

Or possibly:

```
size_t struct_size = offsetof(ring_buffer, data) + capacity * sizeof(void *);
```

Note that `size` should have type `size_t` and you should test for `malloc` failure  to avoid undefined behavor:

```c
ring_buffer *ring_buffer_create(size_t capacity) {
    size_t struct_size = sizeof(ring_buffer) + capacity * sizeof(void *);
    ring_buffer *rb = malloc(struct_size);
    if (rb) {
        rb->capacity = capacity;
        rb->offset = 0;
        rb->size = 0;
    }
    return rb;
}
```